# How is this equation obtained on this page

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, graphing-functions, coordinate-systems

So I have been researching on air resistance and projectile motion, yet I don't get the last part of paper where the writer has a graph with the X and Z axis with a set of equations that I cant find.

How come X=x/(v_0^2/g) and the same for Y=y/(v_0^2/g).
I have included a picture to show you the graph and the equations above.

I also have the sources as a link

http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336k/Newtonhtml/node29.html

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lu2MF.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the dimensionless variables.

It's common practice in computational studies to first remove the dimension by choosing suitable natural units of the system, so that the computer needs only to deal with quantities with no dimension.

Try to follow the derivation of the author, starting from the equations with dimensions at the beginning, and then choose $v_0^2/g$ as the unit of length, and $v_0/g$ as the unit of time to obtain the equation of motions in dimensionless form.

Edit: OK I just read your link in details. In fact your problem with resistance $-cv$ is solved analytically. The computer is used only in the last stage to plot the graph.

So you got
$$x=\frac{v_0v_t\cos\theta}{g}\left(1-e^{-gt/v_t}\right)$$
$$z=\frac{v_t}{g}\left(v_0\sin\theta+v_t\right)\left(1-e^{-gt/v_t}\right)-v_tt$$
where $v_t=mg/c$.

It is not a good idea to set values for all parameters $v_0$, $v_t$, $\theta$, and $g$. Instead you can measure length in units of $v_0^2/g$ and time in units of $v_0/g$. In other words, define the "dimensionless" lengths by
$$X=\frac{x}{v_0^2/g}$$
$$Z=\frac{z}{v_0^2/g}$$
and "dimensionless" time by
$$T=\frac{t}{v_0/g}$$
Then you have
$$X=\frac{v_t}{v_0}\cos\theta\left(1-e^{-(v_0/v_t)T}\right)$$
$$Z=\frac{v_t}{v_0}\left(\sin\theta+\frac{v_t}{v_0}\right)\left(1-e^{-(v_0/v_t)T}\right)-\frac{v_t}{v_0}T$$

Now you see you only need to set two parameters, viz., $v_0/v_t$ and $\theta$ when plotting the graph. Isn't that much simpler?

Comment: It's still confusing me. I'm including this part in my paper, yet I'm just a senior in high school. I still don't understand the last part ;(

Comment: I edited my answer. Please see if you are still confused.

Comment: Ahhh that makes a lot of sense. Thank you !! Quick question then: Is there a normal way to plot this or do I have to use special software?

Comment: And what is a "dimensionless" length like a definition for it in this case.

Comment: May be of some help for knowing the importance of dimensionless equations: https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_purpose_of_dimensionless_equations

Comment: You can just use a for loop to set $T$ varying from $0$ to $t_f$, and print out the $X(T)$ and $Z(T)$. Then use whatever software to plot the two columns or two arrays.

Comment: I am not an expert to give a rigorous definition of the term. May be you can try googling. To me, "dimensionless" means instead of SI units, you choose natural scales of the system and express your quantities in units of those natural scales.

Comment: If you don't want to write a program yourself, you can use a whatever graph software which can plot curves in parametric form. I think e.g., Maxima can do it. May be you can also do it in Excel, I am not sure.

Comment: Thank you very muchhh, you helped me out a lottt :) I wish you the best with your GRE and other academic life !!